# Represent text in Flash Player true to InDesigns representation of text

Tags: flash, adobe-indesign, tlf, indesign-server

I would like to display an editable text field in Flash, with the same text format, columns, padding and letter-spacing, as it would have been defined in an InDesign document.

Is this possible at all? - can the newer Text Layout Format be used to closely present the same set for formats as a user would be able to layout text in InDesign?

-> If so, how would I go about and get the info from InDesign to Flash? - I use an instance of InDesign server, and started out trying to export the text as a swf. The text is exported line by line as instances of the Static Text class, thus cannot be edited client side.

Thank you

Asger

Answer (score 0):

**Shameless self-promotion:** [Prinkk.com](http://www.prinkk.com) features an online Flash editor which comes very close to replicating InDD text layout. This is pure Flash, using TLF, and backed by .NET - no InDesign server at all.

We should have a completely new version out in Q4 of 2012 which will replicate the majority of InDD's core Western text features, with the exception of InDD's proprietary paragraph composition algorithm.

So, yes it is possible, but it has taken us months of development work: it's not something TLF will do for you out of the box, although some people from the InDesign team had a hand in developing TLF, and some of its internal structures are similar to the InDD scripting object model.

Full disclosure: I programmed Prinkk.com and am involved with the enterprise.